# Where can I get REDD dataset if http://redd.csail.mit.edu/ is not working?

Tags: dataset, data-cleaning, data-science-model

Reference Energy Disaggregation Data Set (REDD) is used for research in Non-intrusive Load Monitoring (NILM). Every paper and blogs points towards **http://redd.csail.mit.edu/** as data downling link. However, the link seems not working at all. Has the dataset has been moved to a new location or that it is no longer being maintained?

Could anybody help me to download the REDD dataset?

Thank you.

Comment: I encountered the same problem and just sent the email to the author. Have your problem been solved?

Comment: At https://web.archive.org/web/20220812015008/http://redd.csail.mit.edu the username/password credentials prevented the archiving of compressed dataset files :-(